# What plant is this upright shrub with gorgeous fall color?

Tags: identification, shrubs

This morning I stumbled upon a shrub with incredible autumn shades of leaf colors, including orange, red and yellow. It appears there are several plants of the same kind at the same place. Do you know what plant it is?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is a Prunus, similar to cherries, but not a cherry tree. Cherries also give such beautiful autumn look.

Comment: Yes, this definitely must be Prunus, some kind of cherry. Maybe the Japanese cherry, but we need to see the fruits and blossom before we could be more specific on what species.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi You probably mean saur cherry https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTurKeyg6gfRk0q1jtnzE4wNaPGli6RS_boIlnxAcA54B3M71Fr why dont you write an answer really?

Comment: Because I have no answers. Someone will found the exact name.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I would consider an answer with two or three best guesses a reasonably good answer. Swherlock Holmes never said: "Dr. Watson, we have to wait until spring for evidence..." :)